Polynomial ring over clean ring is clean or not
Let $R$ be a clean ring, does it mean $R[x]$ is also clean? A ring $R$ is said to be clean if each of its element can be written as sum of idempotent and unit.
Let us try to disprove, clearly ring of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is clean, now talk about $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, take polynomial $1+2x$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, can we write $1+2x$ as a sum of idempotent and unit, I think not because $1+2x$ is only unit when $2$ is nilpotent but here $2$ is not nilpotent. So if we write $1+2x$ as $0+(1+2x)$ then $0$ is indeed idempotent but $1+2x$ is not unit. Is it correct?

What you've written is correct, but you cannot conclude $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ isn't clean from what you've written.  It would be easy to classify the idempotents and units in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and use that to conclude, without looking at a particular element, the subset of elements representable as a sum of them.

Your proof is not correct. You only disprove that some decomposition of $1+2x$ is not clean, but this does not disprove the existence of any clean decomposition. Basically, you have just found a non-unit. That's not sufficient.
If $R$ is an integral domain, then $R[X]$ is not clean.
Namely, we have $R[X]^{\times} = R^{\times}$, and $\mathrm{Idem}(R[X]) = \{0,1\}$, so that every clean polynomial is constant.
